# combination of N numbers with preserved order

Tags: math, combinations

In combination problem we all know we can put `2n` items together in `2n!` ways. But say now I have two sets of items:

```
Set A = {a_1, a_2, ...., a_n}, A.length = n
Set B = {b_1, b_2, ...., b_n}, B.length = n
```

My question is: In how many ways you can put this `2n` items together such that their relative order is maintained e.g. `a_i` CANNOT be put before `a_(i-1)` and `b_i` CANNOT be put before `b_(i-1)` but `b_i` can be put before `a_i`.

Example:

```
A=〈a_1, a_2, a_3 〉
B=〈b_1, b_2, b_3 〉
```

Legal formats:

```
a_1 a_2 b_1 a_3 b_2 b_3
b_1 a_1 a_2 b_2 b_3 a_3
```

An Illegal format:

```
a_1 b_2 a_2 b_1 a_3 b_3 (b_2 visited before b_1).
```

Comment: Must all elements be used? i.e. must all generated strings be of length 2n?

Comment: @Sammy: yes all elements must be used and all combinations' length should be 2n

Comment: Essentially, a different phrasing of this seems to be "how many 2n-bit words can be created where exactly n bits are set to 1?". (Since you can then use those words as a set of instructions where a 0 means "take from sequence A" and a 1 means "take from sequence B")

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes, quite exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not searching for combinations, but for *permutations*, more specifically permutations with repetitions. Why? Once you choose `n` positions for the elements from the first set, there is only one way to put elements from the set into these positions (because they have to be in order). The same reasoning applies for the second set. Thus, your problem is equivalent to this one: find the number of binary words of the length `2n` with `n` zeros and `n` ones. And that's something which is learned in any discrete math course, the answer is `(2n)! / (n! * n!)`.

An example for `n = 2`: A = {a_1,a_2}, B = {b_1,b_2}. Possible permutations are:

(a_1, b_1, b_2, a_2),

(a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2),

(a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2),

(b_1, a_1, a_2, b_2),

(b_1, b_1, a_1, 1_2),

(b_1, a_1, b_2, a_2)

which is of course in line with the formula (4!) / (2! * 2!) = 6.

One tip: when calculating this number programmatically for large `n`, be careful about handling overflow. It is not a good practice to first calculate numerator and then dividing by denominators, because there is a good chance of overflow since factorial grows very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: Your calculation is not (2n!). It is (2n)!

Comment: You're most welcome. I verified your answer is correct for sets of 3 by the way. I'm going to have to go find it's derivation.

Answer (score 1):

***Note that this answer is incorrect since you must use everything from both sets in the string and if you choose numbers towards the end of the sequence earlier than you should, numbers later in the string will be out of sequence. You can't choose from all the remaining numbers freely.***

Every time you choose one from either set, it limits your options to those from the second set that are to the right of it, or those to the right of the last one chosen

You choose the 1t from either set first - 2 choices
   That leaves you with n from the other set + n-1 from the set you chose= 2n-1 that you can choose from for the next choice. <-- Can't choose anything from this set. You can only choose the next from either set
   Then 2n-2 for the 3rd and so on
   2*(2n-1)*(2n-2)*(2n-3)....1

Answer is 2*(2n-1)!

I'm tired and it's late so happy to be proven wrong if I am.

Comment: If this answer is incorrect would appreciate knowing what the mistake in the logic is.

Comment: At any particular step, you either have 2 choices (the next item from sequence A or the next item from sequence B) or no choice (if sequence A has been exhausted, you have to take the next item from sequence B, and vice versa)

Comment: @Sammy: Thanks for the answer. I tried to think in your way, at least it gave me some insight about what's going on.

Comment: You start off with 2n choices. You choose 1 and you're always left with 2n-1. What I did do wrong however was that if I want to use them all I have to use them in sequence so I only really have 2 to choose from - the next from one sequence or the next from the other. The other 2n-3 are off limits because if I pick one of them, it won't allow me to pick the preceding numbers which I still have to use.